# Handling Android Push notifications when app is not in the foreground using Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, push-notification

My understanding is to receive the data from push notifications while the app is in the background or not running, one need a service which will put the data somewhere where the app can get at them when it starts up or goes to the foreground. It appears that a common solution is to put the data into the app's Extras.

There are plenty of references for Java but my google-fu fails to find an implementation guide for Delphi.

Also useful would be information on how to "Stack" the notifications into a single notification.

I imagine one could write a single service which is triggered each time a notification arrives, and which then a) puts the data portion of the notification into the app's extras, and b) replaces the notification with a single stacked notification.

My question is "how does one write this service" - some template code would help, and tutorials or reference documents would be great.

FWIW this is for an app with a chat like feature where one doesn't want any notifications to get lost.

Answer (score 0):

One thing at a time... [here's a guide for implementing a service on Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mD3WLK8FYc).

Full disclosure:  I've no idea how effective or useful it is or how complete (or otherwise) Delphi capabilities for Android services are since I use Oxygene for Android development (also Object Pascal but works very differently than Delphi, enabling me to make use of all those Java references).

The rest of your question seems more related to specific business/application requirements than a programming/technical problem, but if you run into specific issues you should consider asking questions about those separately.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Not really business objectives - I need a technical "how-to" guide or reference on how to "replace" the multiple notifications with a single stacked notification when the second, third etc notification arrives.  Also closely related is how to ensure that the app receives the data part of the push notifications, e.g how to write this "background service" (which will probably do both tasks each time a notification arrives)

Comment: For notification "stacking" you need to update an existing notification and all I can do is suggest that you read the Android docs and (try) to adapt it to Delphi if possible (https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html)  

FireMonkey for Android is an NDK solution which isn't really intended for "applications" but primarily intended to support *games*.  You will always be fighting uphill on this stuff. Good luck, but if your app needs these sorts of platform specific services you should reconsider using dev tools more fit for the job.  Delphi sadly really isn't it.